# Python / Kivy Initial Variable Assignment

Tags: python, kivy

I'm relatively new to Python and OOP, and going through the Kivy documentation and found some syntax I was not used to seeing. I am not really sure how to search for the answer since I don't know what to call this type of syntax, so I'll illustrate with the code itself.

Here is the code from the kivy docs:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class Controller(FloatLayout):
    '''Create a controller that receives a custom widget from the kv lang file.

    Add an action to be called from the kv lang file.
    '''
    label_wid = ObjectProperty()
    info = StringProperty()

    def do_action(self):
        self.label_wid.text = 'My label after button press'
        self.info = 'New info text'


class ControllerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Controller(info='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControllerApp().run()
```

When the above code runs

```
return Controller(info='Hello world')
```

I understand that it is setting a value for Controller().info (or controller_object_instance.info within the kivy.app.build() code), but I don't understand how this string assignment to the variable 'info' works, since I would think you would need an **init**() function at the top of the class to accept this assignment. Since there is no **init**() within the Controller() class, why doesn't

```
Controller(info='Hello world')
```

throw an error? How does the above line of code know to properly assign the value 'Hello world' to its own attribute 'info'? Is there some **init**() function inherited from App and this can someone be used or does it have something to do with these two lines of code?

```
label_wid = ObjectProperty()
info = StringProperty()
```

Any help appreciated. Just looking for a way to search for this more on my own, and I'm stuck on what topic to search for.

Comment: `Controller(info='Hello world')` assigns the string 'Hello World' to the variable `info`. It calls the `Controller` function and seeks for the variable `info` to assign that string to it.

Comment: `Controller.__init__` is defined in `FloatLayout.__init__`, search for "inheritance". `Controller(variable=value)` constructs the controller and calls the `__init__ function` from it. `__init__` can do with it as it wants. kivy does "magic" and assigns the value to the info instance variable.

Comment: @syntonym I'm relatively familiar with inheritance, but guess I don't understand it well enough. So when Controller(info='Hello world') passes the argument info='Hello world' to the parent FloatLayout, does this assign a value to FloatLayout.Controller.info or FloatLayout.info? Or am I thinking about the hierarchy wrong altogether?

Comment: I figured out I was thinking about it wrong in my previous comment. When executing `Controller(info='Hello world')`, this creates an instance of Controller which inherits all variables from `FloatLayout` and assigns the string 'Hello world' to the variable `info`. This variable `info` would not be accessed via `FloatLayout.Controller.info` or `FloatLayout.info`, it would solely belong to the newly created object, which in this particular code is not shown as an instance anywhere, but that instance would be passed through the `build()` function's return to somewhere higher in the Kivy code.

Comment: continued... the variable `info` would in fact be assigned in the parent class `FloatLayout` code or possibly an even higher parent class if `FloatLayout` inherets from something else that handles the `__init__()` functionality. Regardless of which parent or grand_parent or gg_parent class code it is assigned in, because of the inheretance, eventually all parent variables, including `info` will be accessable via the object instance created by `Controller(info='Hello world').

Comment: Completly right! Maybe one detail: While you access functions and class variables through inheritance the variable gets actually added to the instance. So if you monkeypatch/change the function in a class all instances will have the "updated" function, because the lookup actually goes to the superclass. For instance variables the lookup does *not* go up to the superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the class `Controller`, you wanted to inherit the class `FloatLayout`.
This means, whenever you create a Controller object, you create a FloatLayout which you extended. So the `__init__` function from FloatLayout at executes.

Look at this example:

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.info = kwargs.get("info")


class Dog(Animal):

    pass


obj = Dog(info="Hello world")

print(obj.info)
```

Now you want to create a `Dog`, but a dog is also an `Animal`, so you want to inherit all it's methods and attributes.
So if you pass `info` as an argument when creating an instance of `Dog`, it will be passed to `Animal`'s `__init__` function.

Comment: I would understand this example, but my question goes a bit deeper regarding variable assignment. In this example, you are only printing a passed keyword. If instead, the Animal.__init__() method assigned the keyword argument to the local variable "info" would this be passed down to the child class Dog? Or would it only be accessible as Animal.info?

Comment: @TopherBuckley, updated the answer. As said, yes Dog inherits all the animals attributes and methods.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That answers my question mostly, but thought about it a bit further and updated my comments to my question above. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!